# Why ng-style for background-image doesn't work?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

My ng-style is as follows, and it does not work for the background:

```
<div
    ng-repeat="s in slider.slides"
    class="slide"
    ng-style="{border: 'solid 4px red', 'background-image': 'url(rsc/selectiontodose/{{s.photo}}.jpg)'}"
    style="width: {{size}}px; height: {{size}}px; margin:0; left:{{-$parent.slide*size}}px;">
</div>
```

I've added the border to make sure the hg-style directive itself is taken into account (and it is as the border is red).

In the DOM, I see no background while the border is actually there.

Any idea?

Comment: Try `ng-style="{'border': 'solid 4px red', 'background-image': 'url(' + s.photo + ')'}`

Comment: Nope, interpolation is Ok (I just did the test tough). @DanielBeck

Comment: You're right about the interpolation, apologies; jumped to conclusions (I often get tripped up by that sort of thing, so...)  Something must be going on in parts your code not shown; what you have should work: http://jsfiddle.net/LSz7W/   Maybe wrong image path?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation, I found that:

```
<div class="splash-banner" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(\'{{banner.backgroundImage}}\')', 'background-color': banner.backgroundColor}">
```

Would render inconsistently compared to:

```
<div class="splash-banner" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(\'' + banner.backgroundImage + '\')', 'background-color': banner.backgroundColor}">
```

Unfortunately I do not know angular as much as I should, but it seemed as though the ng-style expression would evaluate the {{banner.backgroundImage}} before it had a value. I wonder if this is because the banner item was being retrieved from a REST request. It would then default to the url of the current page (or at least current hostname).